# Rails query execution causes database spikes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, postgresql, puma

I'm having a problem with my Rails application where some random queries take around 5 seconds or longer to finish. Most of the time the queries are very simple (`select * from x where id = ?`) and the fields are even indexed too.

Here's some more information about the setup:

- Puma 3.5.0 behind a reversed nginx proxy

  - 4 workers with minimum 4, max 8 threads each.
- Ruby v2.2.3, Rails v4.2.4
- PostgreSQL 9.4 database

  - Thread pool set to max 60 connections
- Appsignal for monitoring
- 8GB RAM, 4 CPU's, SSD.

I found this out when looking at the query performance in Appsignal. I noticed most queries finishing in a few ms and then every now and then, still in the same request, there are multiple queries that take 5+ seconds to finish. And the odd part is that it ALWAYS takes 5,.. seconds.
Here's a picture of that in action:
[image: Appsignal performance]

Things I've tried:

- Increase the thread pool to make sure the puma worker threads have enough connection objects.
- Set 'reaping_frequency' to 10s to make sure there are no dead connections being used.
- Increase puma workers/threads

I'm noticing this in the application as there are some pages that take a long time to load (I have a function call that takes about 1 minute to finish) and somehow this is blocking new requests. This is strange to me as there are 4 workers each with 8 threads = 32 threads that can handle the other requests.

I ran an explain on the query in the picture above, this is the output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=150)
  ->  Index Scan using index_addresses_on_addressable_id_and_addressable_type on addresses  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=150)
        Index Cond: ((addressable_id = 1) AND ((addressable_type)::text = 'University'::text))
        Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
Total query runtime: 13 ms
```

And this is the schema of the addresses table:

```
# Table name: addresses
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  street           :string
#  zip_code         :string
#  city             :string
#  country          :string
#  addressable_id   :integer
#  addressable_type :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  street_number    :string
#  latitude         :float
#  longitude        :float
#  mobile           :string
#  phone            :string
#  email            :string
#  deleted_at       :datetime
#  name             :string`
```

Here's my Puma config file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

directory '/home/deployer/apps/qeystate/current'
rackup "/home/deployer/apps/qeystate/current/config.ru"
environment 'staging'   
pidfile "/home/deployer/apps/qeystate/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/home/deployer/apps/qeystate/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state"
stdout_redirect '/home/deployer/apps/qeystate/shared/log/puma_access.log', '/home/deployer/apps/qeystate/shared/log/puma_error.log', true
threads 4,8
bind 'unix:///home/deployer/apps/qeystate/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock'
workers 4
preload_app!
prune_bundler

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
end
```

Comment: What does explain say? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain Also can we see your migration?

Comment: What migration are you talking about? I'll work on updating the question with an explain query.

Comment: Schema of your addresses table.

Comment: I added the explain query and the schema of the addresses table.

Comment: That does sound like blocking to obtain a new database connection - timeout for that is 5s. Any messages in the logs that seem relevant?

Comment: What's max_connections set to in your Postgres configuration?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I have looked into that possibility by upping the timeout to see if that was the case but it wasn't. The logs don't show any signs of timeout in obtaining connections.

Comment: @mwp haven't touched it, so it's set to the default of 100 connections.

Comment: @RubenHoms It's determined dynamically at startup so it may be worth doing a quick `show max_connections;` just to make sure it's actually 100.

Comment: If decreasing the rails connection pool size makes the issue happen more often, then I'd be inclined to think that was the issue. Increasing it might make the issue happen less often (I assume that it what you mean by thread pool) but won't make it go away completely if you are leaking connections.

Comment: @RubenHoms Another thought occurs, are you using preload_app! in your Puma config? If so, it may be worth sharing your Puma config with us so we can take a look at your on_worker_boot and before_fork handlers.

Comment: @mwp Ran the query, it returns 100 as well. Yes, I am using preload_app! I added the puma config to the question so you can see for yourself.

Comment: @RubenHoms Well, this is certainly a puzzler. Is it possible some other process is occasionally locking the table? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring If I were troubleshooting this I would probably take a look at the middleware stack next. If you can spare the memory, maybe disable preload_app! (and your handlers) and see if the problem goes away. I also might update to Ruby 2.2.4, Puma 3.6.0, and Rails 4.2.7 just to rule out the possibility that this is an already-fixed bug.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm running [a query](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#number-of-active-connections) to check the amount of open connections and with big loads it doesn't increase over ~30 with the threadpool being set to a max of 60 connections.

Comment: @mwp Ran some tests to see if it was a lock occuring but couldn't find anything related to that. I've added a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/HjLgKXE.png) of [pg_top](http://ptop.projects.pgfoundry.org/) running while the system is running a under heavy load. Only weird thing I'm noticing is that one of the processes (the only one with CMD "postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle" is the only one sometimes switching to the 'run' state. The other processes seem to stay in the 'sleep' state. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: How many rows are there in the table? Did you consider adding an index to that table? How often do you write to that table?

Comment: @RubenHoms Maybe your hitting the Rails connection pool bug. [described here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#bad-connections)

Comment: I recommend that you rule out the database as cause, by setting `log_min_duration_statement = 3000` and reading through the log file to see if there were statements that took more than 3 seconds. Or use [pgBadger](http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/) to do it for you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Great idea! I ruled out that the query is actually taking that long since it does not appear in the logs.

Comment: could you change your criteria sequence. Put first addreesable_id and addreesable_type and then deleted_at condition. Try to use rails-footnotes and bullet gem to show where is issue in query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a couple of things - two possible solutions, one testing/reproduction approach, and one suggestion for deeper metrics.

1) Possible quick solution: Spin-off that 1 minute job so it is non-blocking. See if the problem resolves from that. Try using Redis+Sidekiq which is pretty simple to get up and running (or something similar).

2) Second possible solution: Look for any full table locks or exclusive row locks being made to Postgres - see if you EVER make full table locks, and if so, find the offending statement and eliminate it.

3) Testing/replication: For testing, see if you can replicate this problem outside of production. I'd recommend jmeter as a very useful tool to simulate a lot of requests and requests of different types, and see if you can repro this in a controlled/staging context. Consistent replication is the key to resolving issues like this. Refer to your production server logs around the time that the issue occurs to generate your jmeter test requests that will hopefully help reproduce the issue.

If you can figure out a way to replicate it, then you can start tuning the simulation to see if removing or increasing/decreasing various requests eliminates the problem or changes the problem in some way..

4) Analytics: Install NewRelic or similar analytics gem to get a deeper insight into what's going on when that request comes in. You really want to get a solid picture as to whether the request is truly blocked in Postgres (by an exclusive row/table lock that is blocking your query) or whether you are backed up by a slow running query in the Puma execution queue, or somewhere inside Ruby there's an unfortunate wait state somehow.

You don't yet have enough information to solve this issue, so you really want to start exploring solutions by collecting data, alongside hypotheses of what's happening.

My general strategy for this kind of problem is (in this order):

- Try some quick/easy/safe fixes (in the blind) and see if anything is resolved/changed.
- Try to replicate in a non-production environment (really, really try to make this work).
- Instrument the system to collect data to see what you can learn about the problem and anything related.